# I am unable to replicate the following pic. The trouble in the gradient and the Progress indicator

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

1. I want to apply the following background gradient to my app. Also, I want the colour of the gradient to change whenever the user levels up.
2. In the steps indicator, I am unable to make the circle repeat. That is if the steps exceed 10,000 steps then the circle would repeat itself with a deeper shade.
3. Also, how can I add images or icons to the steps progress indicator?[image]

Till now I achieved only maing the progress indicator that too which doesn't function well after 10,000 steps.

Comment: post your `CustomPainter` class then

Comment: It would be great to at least showcase your code so as we can get to understand your thought process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to customize this one. I tried to make `CustomProgressLoader` like your one.

```
class CustomProgressLoader extends StatelessWidget {
  final double progress; // Progress value between 0 and 1

  const CustomProgressLoader({Key? key, required this.progress}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: ProgressLoaderPainter(progress: progress),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProgressLoaderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double progress;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color progressColor;

  ProgressLoaderPainter({
    required this.progress,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.grey,
    this.progressColor = Colors.blue,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double strokeWidth = 10;
    final double radius = size.width / 2 - strokeWidth / 2;
    final Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // Draw the background circle
    final Paint backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, backgroundPaint);

    // Draw the progress arc
    final double sweepAngle = progress * 360;
    final Paint progressPaint = Paint()
      ..color = progressColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius),
      -90 * (3.1415926535897932 / 180),
      sweepAngle * (3.1415926535897932 / 180),
      false,
      progressPaint,
    );

    // Draw the pipe at the end of the progress
    final double pipeLength = 15;
    final double pipeAngle = 90 - sweepAngle;
    final Offset pipeStart = Offset(
      center.dx + radius * (1 - (pipeLength / size.width)) * (progress == 1 ? 1 : -1),
      center.dy,
    );
    final Offset pipeEnd = Offset(
      pipeStart.dx + pipeLength,
      pipeStart.dy,
    );
    final Paint pipePaint = Paint()
      ..color = progressColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    canvas.drawLine(pipeStart, pipeEnd, pipePaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```